# How to set iOS simulator to be consistent with Main.storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am new to Xcode. Built a simple calculator today. However when I run it on simulator it looks different than it is in Main.storyboard. What did I do wrong?

[image: Main.storyboard]

[image: simulator]

Comment: Whats the size of your main storyboard view? are you using auto layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using auto-layout for designing purpose, then you must add constraints for your view's proper positioning. Since you're novice to XCode, you can go through the following tutorial to know and learn about what is auto-layout and constraints.
[Tutorial for auto-layout](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't elaborate how you positioned them on the View.
If you dragged the objects and placed them on the ViewController, you need to setup constraints to the objects if you haven't.